# popd and pushd behavior with "-n" option

Tags: bash, cygwin

I've been experimenting with `pushd` and `popd` in bash (Cygwin, man page says "GNU bash 4.1") and the man page doesn't quite seem to match the behavior.

For `pushd`, the command

```
% pushd +1
```

both rotates the stack and changes the working directory;

```
% pushd -n +1
```

just rotates the stack.  This seems to match the man page.

But

```
% popd +1
```

removes an entry from the stack but does NOT change the working directory (even though "-n" was not supplied).  This does not seem to match the man page, quoted below:

> Arguments, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>
>   **-n**
>   Suppresses  the  normal change of directory when removing
>   directories from the stack, so that  only  the  stack  is manipulated.
>
>   +
>   *n*
>   Removes  the
>   *n*
>   th entry counting from the left of the list
>   shown by
>   **`dirs`**
>   , starting with zero. 
>   For  example:  “
>   `popd +0`
>   ” removes the first directory,
>   “
>   `popd +1`
>   ” the second.

Is this the way it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now experiment with popd/pushd and I think that this is how it is supposed to be. The logic is that `-n` suppresses the change of the directory **if** it should have been without `-n`.

`popd +N` with `N` not equal to zero does not change the directory. It only removes the element from the stack. So in this situation `-n` has to do nothing because it has no change to suppress.

On the contrary, if you use `popd -n` or `popd -n +0`, the second top element of the stack is removed, rather than that at the very top. Because if you removed the top one, your directory would change. I mean if you have:

```
 0  ~/one/two/three
 1  ~/one/two
 2  ~/one
 3  ~
```

when you do `popd +0` or `popd` without `-n`

your current directory is changed to ~/one/two and the dirs stack is now:

```
 1  ~/one/two
 2  ~/one
 3  ~
```

So `-n` should suppress this behavior. And thus, if, **instead** you run `popd -n +0` or `popd -n` you are still in your old directory and the dirs stack is now:

```
 0  ~/one/two/three
 1  ~/one
 2  ~
```

You can see that the second top element ~/one/two was removed, instead of the very top (so that you could stay in your old directory).

So what I try to highlight here is that the top of your dirs stack is always your current directory. And `-n` should prevent the change of the directory. So `-n` should prevent the change of the top of the stack. But if the top of the stack is not changed, the flag `-n` has nothing to do as it is.